# Capybara with Selenium taking too long to load page resulting in Net::ReadTimeout error

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, puma

I am currently running capybara specs that test different functionality of an app. When running my specs, it appears that the page is not being reached  fast enough to test. I have three specs currently, and it takes 9 minutes to end up having them all fail with this same error. Here is the result of running the specs

```
Randomized with seed 38457
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.11.4 , codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:50109
FFF

Failures:

1) Successful source is created
 Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

 1.1) Failure/Error: visit ('/clients/new')

      Net::ReadTimeout:
        Net::ReadTimeout
      # ./spec/qa/variables.rb:12:in `login_user'
      # ./spec/qa/successful_source_spec.rb:7:in `block in (root)'

 1.2) Failure/Error: @io.to_io.wait_readable(@read_timeout) or raise Net::ReadTimeout

      Net::ReadTimeout:
        Net::ReadTimeout
```

Also note that I am using selenium with chrome headless.
Is there anything I can do to have the page load faster so that I can test? This is also the first time these specs are being run.

Comment: Since none of your tests are passing this is more likely to be you using an out of date version of chromedriver than the page taking too long to load

Comment: I am using `chromedriver-helper` version 1.2.0. As far as I can tell, that is the most up to date version.

Comment: The version of `chromedriver-helper` is irrelevant, what matters is what version of `chromedriver` you are actually using??  -- run `bundle exec chromedriver -v`

Comment: Looks like I have `chromedriver` version 2.40.565386 @ThomasWalpole

Comment: That is the latest - so assuming you're also running the latest version of Chrome that wouldn't be the issue.  Check your test.log to see what the app is doing, there's no way it should be taking that long to load - maybe you have left over debugging statements in your code?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong -- the latest is 2.41 and is necessary if you're running Chrome 69 - you may want to update

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I updated `chromedriver` and still am running into the same issue, that does not seem like the fix.

Comment: What versions of chrome, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver, and capybara are you now using?

Comment: Chrome- 67.0.3396.99, Chromedriver-2.4, Selenium-webdriver - 3.13.1, Capybara- 3.4.2 @ThomasWalpole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with a quick fix for this problem. It turns out that the rails server was not connecting to the page fast enough before the test would time out. I decided to change the default wait time in the `spec_helper.rb` to 120 seconds. It will take a lot longer the first time you run the specs, but they eventually will connect and run smoothly from then on. I do not think this is best practice, but it does provide a quick fix to begin testing your specs.